# How do you deal with a multivalued antiderivative for complex integration?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having to integrate functions of the kind $\frac{1}{z}$ on some path. For example the integral:

$\int_{1}^{-1}\frac{dx}{x-i1}$ which corresponds to integrating on a straight line that connects $(1,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ on the complex plane. The result I've got is this one: $\ln\big(\frac{-1-i}{1-i}\big)=\ln\big(\frac{e^{i5\pi/4}}{e^{i7\pi/4}}\big)=-i\frac{\pi}{2}$

But I don't understand anything of what I've done and it raises too many questions. I've assumed that we can only operate with principal angles that range from $[0,2\pi)$...

What does it mean for your antiderivative to be multivalued? Can your integral in fact be multivalued? If we assume that the angles only range $[0,2\pi)$, why is this valid?

Thanks.

Edit: I couldn't find any source online that tackles this sort of problem. If you have one please share. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without going into the entire theory of complex functions, the fundamental theorem of calculus that you used to find the value only works when the function is continuous and thus single-valued *over the range that is being integrated*.

That last sentence is key. We don't necessarily need to use the principle branch of the logarithm, but we do need some branch that is single-valued over the line being integrated. Now the answer you need is $\ln(-1-i) - \ln(1 - i)$. Its identification with $\ln\left (\frac{-1-i}{1-i}\right )$ must also be made with consideration for the branches of the three values being used.

Happily all these problems can be avoided by choosing the branch from $-\pi$ to $\pi$. And your answer is correct. If you had a chosen different branch (though one still avoiding the line of integration), you might have needed to take a little more care in simplifying the logarithmic expression, but the answer you arrived at would still have been $-i\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Which "three values being used" are you referring to? Thx.

Comment: The three you are taking logarithms of: $-1-i, 1-i, \frac{-1-i}{1-i}$. The log of the latter is only equal to the difference of the logs of the first two when it is taken on the appropriate branch.

Comment: With appropriate branch you mean the $-\pi$ to $\pi$ you mention? If I understood correctly then: To use the FTOC you need to specify a branch; $[-\pi,\pi)$ is ideal; Log rule of "quotient-is-difference" has to be handled with care here. Is this a valid summary of this post? Just making sure before I accept your answer.

Comment: Yes, you need to specify a branch that misses the line of integration. And the log rule needs handled with care (more so really than I indicated, but I wanted to keep it simple). Working with $[-\pi, \pi]$ is sufficient to avoid all issues for this particular problem.

Comment: Paul if I use the branch you specify $\int_{1}^{-1} \frac{idy}{-1-iy}$ gives  $-3\pi/2$ while Mathematica gives $-i\pi/2$. Do you think this is Mathematica's problem? I think I've seen elsewhere that Mathematica has its peculiarities with respect to complex numbers.

Comment: I also get $-i\frac{\pi}{2}$, so I think you must have made an error somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Just as in the real case, if you are given an $f$ defned on some open set containing a segment $z_0z_1$, then $F(z)=\int_{z_0}^{z}f(t)dt$ only makes sense if $z\in z_0z_1$. If $f$ is continuous, just as in the real case, we have $F'(z)=f(z)$.

The problem is this: Suppose $z=a+ib$ is some complex number. Now, look at $w=e^{z}=e^{a+ib}=e^a(\cos b+i\sin b)$. This shows that the all the numbers $z_n=a+i(b\pm 2\pi n )$ in the $z$-plane are mapped to the same point $w$ i.e $e^z$ is not one to one and so is not invertible, as it stands.

Geometrically, this means that each horizontal strip of width $2\pi $ in the $z$-plane is mapped onto the $w$-plane punctured at $w=0$. Hence any inverse will not be defined at $0$. Next, notice that in order to choose an inverse, that is a function $w\mapsto z$, we need to choose a particular strip in the $z$-plane to make the inverse well-defined. The will be our logarithm function. There will be many, depending on which strip we choose.

One choice might be: $\left \{ z\in \mathbb C:-\pi\leq \text {Im}z\leq \pi \right \}$ but there is a glitch because $e^{a+i\pi}=e^{a-i\pi }$ and so the inverse is not well-defined. We avoid this problem simply by striking the line Im$z=-\pi$ from our strip and so finally we see that our chosen inverse maps $\mathbb C\setminus \left \{ 0 \right \}$ to $\left \{ z\in \mathbb C:-\pi< \text {Im}z\leq \pi \right \}$ and is indeed well-defined.

Now we can get a formula for the inverse:

Consider the function $w\mapsto \ln \vert w\vert +i\text {Arg}w;\ -\pi<Argw\leq \pi$. It maps $\mathbb C\setminus \left \{ 0 \right \}$ to the strip we chose above.

Furthermore, $\exp \left ( \ln \vert w\vert +i\text {Arg}w \right )=\vert w\vert e^{(i\text {Arg}w)}=w$ so it is the one we want.

It is discontinuous, as you can easily check, at every point on the negative real axis and at $0$ where it is undefined.

The upshot of all this is that $z=\log w$ is well-defined, continuous and differentiable everywhere except on Re$w\leq 0$.

Since your integral is taken along a segment that does not intersect the branch, you may use the fundamental theorem of calculus to evaluate it.

Comment: What is a good google search I can use to read more on this? I've tried many things and haven't seen anything!

Comment: @David what is your math background? I like the book Introduction to Complex Analysis by Nevanlinna Paatero. If you really want to understand these concepts on a more fundamental level, googling may not be the best way to go.

Comment: I study physics and this is part of a mathematical physics course. I'll check that book out. I'm not currently into a fundamental understanding since my time is limited. :(

Comment: I  am confused about what my "segment not intersecting the branch" means. Do you mean my segment doesn't cross $0+0i$?

Comment: As long as the path of integration is bounded away from the half line Re$w≤0$ then the log as we defined it, is the antiderivative of your integrand and so you can use the FTC.